# Ajax Get HTML Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to use this for my class homework, I am still learning.

This is a simple script that check if a site down or not.

What I'm trying to achieve is to use this same script and get statuses for every website on the table without using script all over again. Any solution for this? Any input would be appreciated.

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width:250px">Website</th>
            <th style="width:250px">Is it live</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Google</td>                                    <!-- This is already working. -->

            <td id="website"></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Twitter</td>

            <td id="website" mywebsite="https://Twitter.com"></td>                  <!-- This is what I'm trying to achive. -->


        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Facebook</td>

            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>





<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>



<script type="text/javascript">
    var site = 'https://google.com';
    // var site = 'https://google.com';
    
    $.ajax
    ({
      url: site,
      dataType: "jsonp",
      statusCode: {
          200: function (response) {
              $('#website').html('yes');
            console.log(response);
          },
          404: function (response) {
              $('#website').html('no');
            console.log(response);
          }
      } 
     });
</script>
```

Comment: Duplicate IDs are a no-no in HTML. Use classes.

Comment: Just FYI what you're attempting to do will not work. You cannot make a cross-domain AJAX request due to the Same Origin Policy and the resulting CORS restrictions in place. If you want this to work, you'll have to make the requests from the server side (ie. PHP, C#, Node etc.)

Comment: Thanks for that. I didn't know that before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `id="website"` because an id is an unique value, use `class="website"` in your html.

```
<td class="website"></td>
```

IN your jQuery the change is simple instead of using `#` use `.` is used for references to classes (ie. website), like so:

```
$(".website").html("yes");
```

Don't forget to modify all locations. This will execute for all places where `class="website"` is defined.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for this. I tried this and it worked like before. But as I stated before how can I use this same script for all three websites?.

Comment: Extract the jQuery code and store it in it's own *.js file and ensure that it is accessible in the locations you want to use it.

Comment: If you included jQuery in your project it would be pretty much the same way but you need to reference the file location within your project.

Answer (score 1):

Put your `url` on `data attribute` and `loop` to get value from `td` like this.

```js
$('table > tbody > tr').find('td').each(function() {
  var site = $(this).data('url');
  $.ajax({
    url: site,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    statusCode: {
      200: function(response) {
        $('#website').html('yes');
        console.log(response);
      },
      404: function(response) {
        $('#website').html('no');
        console.log(response);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="width:250px">Website</th>
      <th style="width:250px">Is it live</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td data-url='https://google.com'>Google</td>
      <!-- This is already working. -->

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-url="https://twitter.com/">Twitter</td>


      <!-- This is what I'm trying to achive. -->


    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-url="https://www.facebook.com/">Facebook</td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
```

Comment: This isn't working - your own snippet even shows that. Cross-domain issues aside the response would be HTML, not JSONP